# ¿Cómo sumo una columna de una tabla de un array en Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Tengo el siguiente archivo `.txt`, que abrí con `File.Open("productos.txt", "r")`.

El caso es que este archivo viene con el siguiente formato.

```
Producto1, 10, 15, 21
Producto2, 20, 0, 3
Producto3, 4, 8, 0
Producto8, 1, 2, NR
Producto12, NR, 2, NR
```

Y tengo que sumar los números de la primera columna, además se me hace complicado ya que el último número de la columna es un *string* y tengo que transformarlo.

En resumen, debo hacer esa suma a partir de la **columna**, y no encuentro la manera de hacer esa separación o llegar a esa **posición**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando que el archivo no es muy grande (como en tu ejemplo), yo haría lo siguiente:

- Leer todo el contenido del archivo
- Crear un arreglo con cada línea
- Crear un arreglo para cada línea con los valores
- Convertir los valores de la primera columna a número y sumarlos

En código se vería así:

```
File.read("productos.txt")
    .map(&:strip)
    .sum { |producto| producto.split(",")[1].to_i }
#=> 35
```

En caso que el archivo sea muy grande, podrías optar por utilizar `File.foreach` en lugar de `File.read` para leer el archivo línea por línea; por ejemplo:

```
File.foreach("productos.txt").sum { |producto| producto.split(",")[1].to_i }
#=> 35
```

**Es importante destacar que al aplicar `to_i` a un *string* que *no inicia con un número*, el resultado siempre es `0`**.

Ejemplos:

```
"10".to_i    #=> 10
"NR".to_i    #=> 0
"NR10".to_i  #=> 0
"10NR".to_i  #=> 10
"01NR".to_i  #=> 1
```

Comment: Me sale un error de sugerencia que ocupe otros tipos de each, como si each_line no existiera. Estoy ejecutando este código dentro de un case when 1, ya que es una de las opciones que debo mostrar.

Comment: @UpsetGrade Puedes cambiar `each_line` por `map`; aunque yo prefiero la segunda opción (`File.foreach`), es más corta. Si lo utilizas en um `case`, te recomiendo poner el código en un método y simplemente llama ese método en el `case`.

Comment: Gerry, y si quiero mostrar solamente los productos no registrados?

Comment: @UpsetGrade Cambia `sum` por `select`: `File.foreach("productos.txt").select { |producto| producto.split(",")[1].strip == "NR" }`. Agregué `strip` para quitar los espacios sobrantes.